# InnerHTML en ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Al ejecutar el evento `onSubmit`, donde construyo tabla y la renderizo con InnerHtml, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema que me surge es el evento onClick, que deseo llamar a una función y no se como hacer para llamarla.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
class ListaLiquidaciones extends Component {

onSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let objeto = this.props.lista_resultado_liquidaciones;
        const objetoStr = JSON.stringify(objeto);
        let data = JSON.parse(objetoStr);
        let html = "<table class=\"table\"> <tr><th>#</th><th>Fecha de Novedad</th><th>Seller</th><th>Concepto</th><th>Estado</th><th>Importe</th><th>Acciones</th></tr><tbody>";
        let liquidado;
        var j = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            html = html + "<tr>";
          
            
              
                liquidado = "<button onClick=\"nuevaLiquidacion()\" type=\"button\" className=\"btn btn - sm\">Nueva Liquidación</button>";

                


            
            html = html + "<td>" + liquidado + "</td>";
    
            html = html + "</tr>";
            j++;
 
            
        }
        html = html + "</tbody> </table >";
        document.getElementById("tabla_lista_novedades").innerHTML = html;

}
}
```

Comment: Por que dibujarías una tabla con innerHTML en react?.. Cual es tu idea, favor pasar más información para poder entender y ayudarte. Técnicamente si estás trabajando con React evitarías la manipulación directa del DOM por JavaScript..

Comment: Claro, como te comentan, tu lógica está errada de base. El objetivo de usar React, es justamente evitar manipular el DOM directamente con JavaScript utilizando propiedades como `innerHTML`, a no ser que haya una razón excepcional estrictamente necesaria. Las herramientas que te da React te dan otras alternativas mucho más útiles, como utilizar [JSX](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) o los [estados](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html). Te recomendamos que hagas un curso completo de React, o leas la parte de su documentación que habla sobre eso.